# Find a basis of Ker and Im, some clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I would like some clarification about the following exercise, for there are things I dont' really understand well.
I have a linear application $F: V \to W$, where I have a basis for $V$ denoted as $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ and threee vectors of $W$, $(w_1, w_2, w_3)$ such that only the first two are linearly independent, whilst $w_3 = w_1+w_2$.

$F$ sends $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ into $(w_1, w_2, w_3)$ and I have to find a basis for Ker and Im of $F$.

- What I don't get is: can/could/should I treat the problem symbolically or may I choose $v_k = e_k$, the canonical basis in order to simplify a bit?
- Though not knowing $w_k$, I cannot calculate $F(e_k)$ and create the associated matrix.

How would I proceed in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess the $w_k$'s are the same as the $c_k$'s ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Right, going to edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of $F$ is $\{\alpha w_1+\beta w_2\,:\,\alpha,\beta\in\mathcal F\}$, where $\mathcal F$ is the field that you are working with. In particular, $\dim\operatorname{Im}F=2$. Since $\dim V=3$, $\dim\ker F=1$, by the rank-nullity theorem. But $v_3-v_1-v_2\in\ker F$. Therefore, $\ker F=\{\alpha(v_3-v_1-v_2)\,:\alpha\in\mathcal F\}$.

Besides, $\{w_1,w_2\}$ is a basis of $\operatorname{Im}F$ and $\{v_3-v_1-v_2\}$ is a basis of $\ker F$.

Comment: Why the downvote? I was going to read this and try to understand it...

Comment: And the downvote prevents you from doing that?

Comment: No, but I'm used to the fact that sometimes people downvote answers because they are wrong, so I got stuck a little. Of course I am reading it

Comment: @Another User This is a simple and clear explanation.

Comment: Just a technical question: instead of saying the image of $F$ is $\alpha w_1 + \beta w_2$ can I say too that Im$(F) = \text{span}(w_1, w_2)$ or is it wrong?

Comment: No, it is not wrong.